# Verifying Computation of Limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$.

I have to compute the limit of: lim$\left(\displaystyle\frac{(a_n+2)^2-4}{a_n}\right)$.

From this I obtained: lim$(\left(\displaystyle\frac{(a_n+2)^2-4}{a_n}\right) =$ lim$\left(\displaystyle\frac{a_n^2+4a_n+4-4}{a_n}\right)$.

Using the Algebraic Limit Theorem: lim$\left(\displaystyle\frac{a_n^2+4a_n}{a_n}\right)$ = $\displaystyle\frac{\text{lim}(a_n^2)+4\text{lim}(a_n)}{\text{lim}(a_n)} =$ $\displaystyle\frac{0}{0}$.

Since $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form, we use L'Hospital's Rule:

lim$\displaystyle\frac{a_n^2+4a_n}{a_n}$ = $\displaystyle\frac{\text{lim}(2a_n+4)}{\text{lim}(1)} =$ $\displaystyle\frac{2\text{lim}(a_n)+\text{lim}(4)}{1}$ = $\displaystyle\frac{4}{1}=4$

Comment: It's just $\infty$. Your computations are wrong.

Comment: sorry can you explain? i have to show computation

Comment: The nominator $\rightarrow8$ and the denominator $\rightarrow0$.

Comment: I get the feeling there's a typo in the question, where it should have been $-4$ and not $+4$ in the numerator.

Comment: @AlexR. you are right..typo on my end

Comment: i fixed my answer above

Comment: No, it is most definitely not right. You wrote $0/0 = 0$.

Comment: i remember from previous calc classes that when we get $\frac{0}{0}$ we are supposed to use l'hospitals rule..?

Comment: @user296602 i edited my answer above using your correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After simplification, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(a_n+2)^2-4}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+4)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)+4=4.$$